# menuitem id in xml format can't be an integer? huh. really?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

ok, in menu.add, you add an integer menuitem id.

But when you specify the menu in xml, @+id can't take an integer, so you can't test the id for the menu item as an integer in a switch statement.

What obvious thing am I missing, because surely an inconsistency this bone-stupid couldn't have passed muster with all those wonderful geniuses at Google.

on top of that, when I give the menu item a name like "@+id/myMenuItem", item.getItemId() returns an integer, a long one, which I guess is a representation of the hex pointer.

M

Answer (score 6):

You can't specify the id attribute in XML as an integer because all ids are (in the build process) generated *into* an integer, and then placed into R.java for access later.  If they let you name it an integer, then you wouldn't be creating legal Java code (because Java variables can't just be a number).

In other words, if you name an id "@+id/something", then in R.java there is a static variable "something" which contains the integer id for the id.  Then in code, you access it like this when the user clicks the menu item:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.something: {
        // Do something here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: The fact that ids are converted to integer values isn't really relevant to the question (though useful to know :)), but the id is converted to a Java constant name in R.x.id, as such (like commonsware already said) they can not begin with a number.

Answer (score 1):

`@id` values have to map to Java names (`@id/foo` turns into `R.id.foo`), and you can't have a Java name that is pure numeric. I'm not even sure it can start with a number.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this example:

```
private static final int EDIT_ID = Menu.FIRST + 3;
private static final int DELETE_ID = Menu.FIRST + 4;
 @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
            ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, EDIT_ID, Menu.NONE, "Edit").setAlphabeticShortcut(
                'e');
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, DELETE_ID, Menu.NONE, "Delete")
                .setAlphabeticShortcut('d');
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case EDIT_ID:

            edit(info.id);
            return (true);
        case DELETE_ID:

            delete(info.id);
            return (true);
        }

        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }
```

Comment: The question is talking about xml menus, not programmed menus.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Very fast and accurate.